# Simple systemd timer won't fire

Tags: bash, timer, systemd, archlinux

I've wrote this script to backup my sql files both physically (copy the databases) and logically (pg_dumpall).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Backup-Skript für Postgresql

# Dump aller Datenbanken.
/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_dumpall > /mnt/backup/postgresql/pg_backup.bak

# "Physisches" Kopieren des Datenbankverzeichnises.
/opt/rsync/bin/rsync -avu /mnt/evc/postgresql/var/data /mnt/backup/postgresql/
# Dieser Ordner enthält auch die Konfigurationsdateien.
# Daher müssen diese nicht separat kopiert werden.
```

The following systemd unit uses this script.

```
[Unit]
Description=Sicherung der Datenbanken (Postgresql)
DefaultDependencies=no
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=postgresql
Group=postgresql
ExecStart=/opt/postgresql/Scripts/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It is not enabled.

Then the following enabled timer unit is supposed to run the service once every 15 minutes.

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup des Postgresql-Servers alle 15 Minuten
Requires=backup-postgresql.service

[Timer]
# Alle 15 Minuten.
OnCalendar=*:0,15,30,45
Persistent=true
Unit=backup-postgresql.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Yet the timer won't fire. Once the hit zero the first time, the service is executed bud

```
sudo systemd list-timers --all
```

shows:

```
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Thu 2020-02-06 00:00:00 CET  15h left Wed 2020-02-05 08:25:59 CET  20min ago    shadow.timer                 shadow.service
Thu 2020-02-06 08:40:57 CET  23h left Wed 2020-02-05 08:40:57 CET  5min ago     systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
n/a                          n/a      Wed 2020-02-05 08:45:00 CET  1min 32s ago backup-postgresql.timer      backup-postgresql.service
```

Additional info: I'm on arch with kernel 5.5.1-arch1-1.

Comment: I may be wrong (and it wouldn't be the first or last time) but isn't that `OnCalendar` entry every 15 *seconds* (`minutely` maps to `*-*-* *:*:00`)? Shouldn't it be `*:0,15,30,45:0`?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I think to fire every 15 seconds it would need an extra `*:` (eg. `*:*:0,15,30,45`). Maybe try `OnUnitActiveSec=15min` and see if that works.

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately nothing has changed. Even after reboot.

Comment: you did **enable** the *timer* unit, did you?

Comment: I did, yes. The Service unit however isn't enabled.

Comment: I think `RemainAfterExit=yes` is the problem.  This means the service will remain started until stopped.  The timer doesn't stop the service. It just starts it every 15 min.  Therefore since the service is already started, it doesn't go again. 
Try removing `RemainAfterExit=yes`

Answer (score 1):

For your service file, you don't need:

- `DefaultDependencies=no`,
- `RemainAfterExit=yes`, or
- `[Install]` section.

I think `RemainAfterExit` is the problem because it keeps the service started, even after the process is done.  That means it when the timer tells the service to start again, it'll be ignored because the service is still on.

For your timer file, you don't need the following as long as your timer has the same name as your service:

- `Requires=backup-postgresql.service`
- `Unit=backup-postgresql.service`

In fact, `Requires` might be a problem because it triggers the backup as soon as you start the timer and also fails the timer if the services fails to start.

Use `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing these files to allow them to be re-read by systemd.  Check `systemctl status backup-postgresql` to see if the service is hanging after the `RemainAfterExit` issue and use `systemctl stop backup-postgresql` to recover if it is stuck running.

---

To give a simple template, I just created a simple timer from scratch:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/timeprint.timer
[Unit]
Description=Print time every minute

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/1

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/timeprint.service
[Unit]
Description=Print time

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/date
```

If you make a change to these files you'll need to run `systemctl daemon-reload`

I enabled with:

```
systemctl enable timeprint.timer
systemctl start timeprint.timer
```

Then I checked the timer with:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-timers timeprint
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED  UNIT            ACTIVATES
Wed 2020-02-05 13:00:00 CET  16s left Wed 2020-02-05 12:59:08 CET  35s ago timeprint.timer timeprint.service

1 timers listed.
$ sudo journalctl -u timeprint
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-01-28 06:55:16 CET. --
Feb 05 12:58:24 stewbian systemd[1]: timeprint.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 12:58:24 stewbian systemd[1]: Started Print time.
Feb 05 12:59:08 stewbian systemd[1]: Starting Print time...
Feb 05 12:59:08 stewbian date[185510]: Wed  5 Feb 12:59:08 CET 2020
Feb 05 12:59:08 stewbian systemd[1]: timeprint.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 12:59:08 stewbian systemd[1]: Started Print time.
Feb 05 13:00:24 stewbian systemd[1]: Starting Print time...
Feb 05 13:00:24 stewbian date[185540]: Wed  5 Feb 13:00:24 CET 2020
Feb 05 13:00:24 stewbian systemd[1]: timeprint.service: Succeeded.
Feb 05 13:00:24 stewbian systemd[1]: Started Print time.
```

Comment: This answer contradicts with [this documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Management) which says that you should enable the `.timer` unit rather than the `.service` unit. Which is correct?

Comment: You are right, enable the `.timer`, not the `.service`.  Answer fixed.  Enabling the service won't do anything because there is no `[Install]` section.